# ArcGIS .Net Framework SDK for 10.8: Does not install correctly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.8

When using the installer:  *ArcObjects_SDK_for_NET_Framework_108_172796*
with having Visual Studio 2017 and ArcGIS 10.8 installed, the select features is missing the VS 2017 (see second image)

Steps already taken:

- Uninstalled ArcGIS 10.8 and reinstalled it.
- Updated VS 2017

Any suggestions?

[image: Missing VS 2017 items]

[image: Expected Options]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling ArcGIS Desktop and Visual Studio fixed the issue. It might have been the order of the install.